# I have to set up an Interrupt file for a virtual keypad when pressing buttons in arm assembly komodo

Tags: assembly, arm, komodo

I have a virtual board with numbers on them from 1-9 and I have to set up an interrupt file to check for key de-bouncing. Can anyone help?